# Generate all combinations

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table storing attributes and their values.

```sql
DECLARE @temp table
(
    attribute varchar(10),
    value varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES
('height', '1.6m'),
('height', '1.8m'),
('weight', '50kg'),
('weight', '80kg'),
('gender', 'male'),
('gender', 'female')
```

I want to generate all the combinations of these attributes regardless of how many attributes there are in the table.

```
|Combination |Attribute |Value  |
|------------|----------|-------|
|1           |height    |1.6m   |
|1           |weight    |50kg   |
|1           |gender    |male   |
|2           |height    |1.6m   |
|2           |weight    |50kg   |
|2           |gender    |female |
|3           |height    |1.6m   |
|3           |weight    |80kg   |
|3           |gender    |male   |
|4           |height    |1.6m   |
|4           |weight    |80kg   |
|4           |gender    |female |
|5           |height    |1.8m   |
|5           |weight    |50kg   |
|5           |gender    |male   |
|6           |height    |1.8m   |
|6           |weight    |50kg   |
|6           |gender    |female |
|7           |height    |1.8m   |
|7           |weight    |80kg   |
|7           |gender    |male   |
|8           |height    |1.8m   |
|8           |weight    |80kg   |
|8           |gender    |female |
```

I think CTE is needed but can't think of the way to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to preprogram the number of attributes in the table.  You just want all combinations however many there are.

That suggests a recursive CTE.  I think it is simplest to get the combinations in strings -- all the rows for a combination on one row.  And for this it helps if there is an `id` column in `temp`.  So, I'll assume one exists.

So, to get the groupings of ids:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, 
             dense_rank() over (order by attribute) as attribute_seqnum
      from temp t
     ),
     cte as (
      select t.attribute, t.value, attribute_seqnum, 1 as lev, convert(varchar(max), t.id) as ids
      from t 
      where attribute_seqnum = 1
      union all
      select t.attribute, t.value, t.attribute_seqnum, lev + 1, concat(ids, ',', t.id)
      from cte join
           t
           on t.attribute_seqnum = cte.attribute_seqnum + 1

     )
select *
from (select cte.*, max(lev) over () as max_lev
      from cte
     ) x
where lev = max_lev;
```

This works by enumerating the attributes in `temp` and then adding them one at a time.

You can unsplit the ids and join back to the table to get separate rows:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, 
             dense_rank() over (order by attribute) as attribute_seqnum
      from temp t
     ),
     cte as (
      select t.attribute, t.value, attribute_seqnum, 1 as lev, convert(varchar(max), t.id) as ids
      from t 
      where attribute_seqnum = 1
      union all
      select t.attribute, t.value, t.attribute_seqnum, lev + 1, concat(ids, ',', t.id)
      from cte join
           t
           on t.attribute_seqnum = cte.attribute_seqnum + 1

     )
select x.seqnum, t.attribute, t.value
from (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum, x.*
      from (select cte.*, max(lev) over () as max_lev
            from cte
           ) x
      where lev = max_lev
     ) x cross apply
     string_split(ids, ',') s join
     temp t
     on t.id = convert(int, s.value);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90b2d5013829a8335fa73228da9655b2) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  You don't have to have an `id` in `temp` for this to work.  You can store the attribute/value pairs at each step in the recursion.  However, I think that just adds some additional complication.

Answer (score 2):

The following query seems to be working, and yes, it uses a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM (SELECT attribute AS attr1, value AS val1 FROM temp WHERE attribute = 'height') t1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT attribute AS attr2, value AS val2 FROM temp WHERE attribute = 'weight') t2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT attribute AS attr3, value AS val3 FROM temp WHERE attribute = 'gender') t3
)

SELECT rn AS Combination, attr1 AS Attribute, val1 AS Value FROM cte WHERE attr1 = 'height' UNION ALL
SELECT rn, attr2, val2 FROM cte WHERE attr2 = 'weight' UNION ALL
SELECT rn, attr3, val3 FROM cte WHERE attr3 = 'gender'
ORDER BY Combination, Attribute, Value;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

This approach uses a series of cross joins to generate an intermediate table (the CTE) which contains one record for each combination.  There are 8 combinations, given 3 attributes with 2 values each.  Then, we use a series of unions to unpivot that into the long form result you want.

Comment: what if the number of attributes is variable?

Comment: That's _not_ the question you asked, and the site doesn't work this way.  If you have a _different_ requirement, you should ask a new question, not force others to continually update/edit their answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as
 (
   select
      -- combination number
      row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn
     ,t1.attribute as a1
     ,t1.value     as v1
     ,t2.attribute as a2
     ,t2.value     as v2
     ,t3.attribute as a3
     ,t3.value     as v3
   -- create all combinations, each attribute needs an extra join
   from @temp as t1
   join @temp as t2 on t1.attribute < t2.attribute
   join @temp as t3 on t2.attribute < t3.attribute
 )
select c.*
from cte
-- unpivot using CROSS APPLY 
cross apply
(
  values
    (rn, a1, v1),
    (rn, a2, v2),
    (rn, a3, v3)
) c (combination, attribute, value)
order by 1,2,3;
```

Every additional attribute requires an extra join, two columns in Select list and a VALUES in CROSS APPLY.

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5114bbe34b68ea5fe4904c9bb3a6ec6c)

Of course this query can be created using Dynamic SQL based on `select distinct attribute`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `cross join` and [`unpivot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) to achieve this.

**cross join**

```
select  row_number() over(order by t_h.attribute) as 'combo',
        t_h.*, t_w.*, t_g.*
from @temp t_h
cross join @temp t_w
cross join @temp t_g
where t_h.attribute = 'height'
  and t_w.attribute = 'weight'
  and t_g.attribute = 'gender';


combo                attribute  value      attribute  value      attribute  value
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1                    height     1.6m       weight     50kg       gender     male
2                    height     1.6m       weight     50kg       gender     female
3                    height     1.8m       weight     50kg       gender     male
4                    height     1.8m       weight     50kg       gender     female
5                    height     1.6m       weight     80kg       gender     male
6                    height     1.6m       weight     80kg       gender     female
7                    height     1.8m       weight     80kg       gender     male
8                    height     1.8m       weight     80kg       gender     female
```

**unpivot**

I moved the previous query into a CTE, but a subquery is also possible.

```
with cte_source as (
    select  row_number() over(order by t_h.attribute) as 'combo',
            t_h.attribute as 'att_h',
            t_h.value as 'val_h',
            t_w.attribute as 'att_w',
            t_w.value as 'val_w',
            t_g.attribute as 'att_g',
            t_g.value as 'val_g'
    from @temp t_h
    cross join @temp t_w
    cross join @temp t_g
    where t_h.attribute = 'height'
      and t_w.attribute = 'weight'
      and t_g.attribute = 'gender'
)
select  up.combo,
        case up.x
            when 'val_h' then 'height'
            when 'val_w' then 'weight'
            when 'val_g' then 'gender'
        end as 'attribute',
        up.val as 'value'
from cte_source s
unpivot (val for x in (val_h, val_w, val_g)) up;


combo                attribute value
-------------------- --------- ----------
1                    height    1.6m
1                    weight    50kg
1                    gender    male
2                    height    1.6m
2                    weight    50kg
2                    gender    female
3                    height    1.8m
3                    weight    50kg
3                    gender    male
4                    height    1.8m
4                    weight    50kg
4                    gender    female
5                    height    1.6m
5                    weight    80kg
5                    gender    male
6                    height    1.6m
6                    weight    80kg
6                    gender    female
7                    height    1.8m
7                    weight    80kg
7                    gender    male
8                    height    1.8m
8                    weight    80kg
8                    gender    female
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at a simple solution

```
;with
rows_cte([name], attribute, rn) as (
    select v.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) from 
    (select [value] h, attribute a from @temp where attribute='height') h
    cross join
    (select [value] w, attribute a from @temp where attribute='weight') w
    cross join
    (select [value] g, attribute a from @temp where attribute='gender') g
    cross apply 
    (values (h, h.a), (w, w.a), (g, g.a)) v(n, a))
select ((rn-1)/3)+1 combination, rc.attribute, rc.[name]
from rows_cte rc
order by combination;
```

Comment: It's so simple that it doesn't return the expected result :-)

Answer (score -1):

maybe :

```
select t1.attribute, t2.value from tab t1, tab t2
```

or if you need unique:

```
select t1.attribute, t2.value
from 
(select distinct attribute from tab) t1,
(select distinct value from tab ) t2
```